# GWT Chart - charts class path error on compile

Tags: java, gwt, google-visualization

I am trying to produce my first chart in GWT Java. I have copied the sample and included both gwt-visualization-1.1.2.jar and gwt-charts-0.9.3.jar using properties --> Java Build Path --> Libraries tab --> Add External Jars.

[image]

I then added:

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.visualization.Visualization"/>
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.charts.Chart"/>
```

to my .gwt.xml. However, I am still betting the following error when I compile:

```
  Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.charts.Chart'
  [ERROR] Unable to find 'com/google/gwt/charts/Chart.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
```

What have I missed please?

Comment: Try to clear your path, copy JARs to `\war\WEB-INF` and then use `Add JARs` (not external).

Comment: I have done as you suggest and still had the error. I upgraded to gwt-charts-0.9.10 and I still get the error.